# How to make model objects uneditable after first submission by users

Tags: python, django, django-models, user-profile

I have a profile model all set up. I have also been able to render the data to the template, however, this is currently editable by logged in users.

My plan, however, is to give users one-off access to fill their data themselves, and once they submit it, such data can not be edited by them except user with is_staff or superadmin privileges, even though they are going to see their data in their profile view.

Is this possible? If yes, what strategy and/or example can I follow as I have no idea whatsoever on how to go about this.

## views.py

```
@transaction.atomic
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        employee_form = EmployeeProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and employee_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            employee_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account successfully updated!')
            return render(request, 'accounts/update-profile.html')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the error(s) below')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        employee_form = EmployeeProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'accounts/update-profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'employee_form': employee_form,
    })
```

Comment: Via the admin or a custom view? If a custom view please share it

Comment: @IainShelvington I have no idea how to do that, the last sentence in my question revealed that. However, I currently have a `def edit_profile` function view which gives logged in users access to edit their profiles. Based on the business login I have in my head, I want a situation whereby users can only submit their information once but never get the chance to edit it except by an admin user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [generic class based views provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) it's fairly simple. The mixin [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) adds a method `test_func` to a view that you can use to return `True` or `False` if the user has permission or not

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin


class ProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    # Used for creation - has no special permissions
    model = Profile


class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    # Used for viewing - has no special permissions
    model = Profile


class ProfileUpdateView(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    # Used for updating - requires a user be superuser or staff
    model = Profile

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Iain. I'm not sure I am doing the right thing as I have been battling with it since you last posted your comment. But if I may ask, how can I pass in my current view function (you can see my edited post) into the class based `class ProfileUpdateView(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView)?

Comment: Why is there a user form and a profile form in a view that's just updating a profile?

Comment: I followed [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) by extending my User model using a `OneToOne link`. And because the data in my Profile model is a bit legthy, I choose to use two forms to update the information.